# Arara rule for gnuplot in Texstudio on Windows 10

Tags: gnuplot, auto-completion, arara

I run gnuplot with a user command

```
pdflatex --shell-escape %.tex
```

perfectly.

Is there any rule for arara to automate this process to be used, instead of running arara then user defined then arara again?..

Comment: If there is none in the manual, there is no predefined rule. But you can always write one (maybe you should take the metapost or asymptote rules as inspiration).

Comment: TeXnician, there is no predefined rule and I do not know how to write one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The team [just commited](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/commit/b27e7af4cc953dab24f96b40ed0f48678e900ace) a new `gnuplot` rule in the [development branch](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/tree/development) of `arara`, so it might reach the general public in the upcoming maintenance release, yet to be scheduled.

You can get the `gnuplot` rule [from the repository](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/blob/development/rules/gnuplot.yaml) and include the path in a global/local configuration (e.g, `arararc.yaml`, as described in the user manual). Then you can compile your plot with:

```
% arara: gnuplot: { input: [ myplot.gnuplot ] }
```

It is important to note that `input` is a required parameter and takes a list of files to be processed by `gnuplot`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Paulo Cereda, Thanks for the answer but it gives me the error "Maybe you need to enable the shell-escape feature? For pdflatex, this is '>> pdflatex -shell-escape'. You can also invoke '>> gnuplot <file>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file..".. I do not know what this means?

Comment: @kosofo You probably need to enable shell escape in your engine rule, e.g, `pdflatex: { shell: yes }` might suffice...

Comment: Paulo Cereda, thank you, that`s great....

Comment: Paulo Cereda, please, there is an error "line 0: Cannot open script file 'myplot.gnuplot'

--------------------------- FAILURE".... what it means?

Comment: It means the file to be plotted by `gnuplot` does not exist. You need to specify the file name for `gnuplot` to process through `arara`...